# Area level security for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-3

I know it is possible to decorate a controller with the Authorize attribute to control access, what I don't know is the accepted or proper way to enforce security across all the controllers/views in an Area.

Is there something in web.config, area registration or some other place to apply authorization security?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A convenient way is to create a new base class

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class AuthorizeBaseController :  Controller
{
}
```

and make sure that all of your controllers for which you require authorization (in your case, everything in the area that you're concerned about) descend from `AuthorizeBaseController`.

```
public class HomeController : AuthorizeBaseController
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

The `[Authorize]` attribute should affect all of the descendents of the new base class.

**Edit** The issue that I have with using the `<location path="" >` approach is that, since the routing engine makes it's possible for any route to call any controller, setting authorization based on the url (and thus a specific route) instead of the controller actions makes it possible to call a controller that should be protected and skip the authorization. That wasn't an issue in webforms since a page was a page (and not a method call), but the separation between page/path and code in MVC makes this a huge security hole.

Comment: Your method is suggested as the old method for MVC2.  Not at all suggesting you are incorrect.  Here is a link to the new and improved technique for MVC3 using Global Filters http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Comment: Your welcome, and that's quite a compliment, since I only started trying to learn MVC3 on Tuesday. :)

Answer (score 7):

The **only** safe way of doing this in an MVC application is to do what David suggests - attributing a base controller and having all controllers in the area subclass that base controller.

Using a <location> tag for authorization in MVC **will** open security holes in your application.  You're not interested in securing URLs or routes.  You want to secure the controllers themselves, since they're the actual resources you're trying to protect.  Therefore the protections need to be placed directly on the controllers.

Furthermore, remember that an area is really just a fancy way of grouping *routes*, not controllers.  Trying to use fancy logic to detect the current area and infer authorization settings will also open security holes in your application.

Answer (score 0):

As was already suggested, you can make use of the `<location />` element in your web.config. Otherwise, you can use a base controller class per-area and decorate that with the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) so that all controllers which inherit from it are also filtered.

Answer (score -3):

you can always use 
`<location path="" >
<system.web> 
<authorization> 
deny or allow 
</authorization>
</system.web> 
</location>`

Comment: Do not use web.config methods for securing MVC applications, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx

Comment: Down voting due to other answers explicitly stating that you shouldn't do this...and why you shouldn't do this.