# Allowing access to specific view with parameters in mvc 3 and Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have view with parameters like reset password with parameter key

```
 public ActionResult ResetPassword(string Email,string Key)
       {
            //Do some thing
            return View();
        }
```

and I am using forms authentication.
What I want is to allow unauthorized users to access this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add location in web.Config and set allowOverride="false" like

```
<location path="reset.password" allowOverride="false">    
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This solve my problem. Thanks all :)

Comment: But I'd still recommend **not to do it this way in Asp.net MVC**, because it may be very confusing since such paths don't physically exist on the disk and routing may get changed any time making this setting obsolete. Using `AuthorizeAttribute` will keep working even when routing changes because it's attached to controller action directly.

Comment: A MS reference that says that [web.config is not a place to secure your Asp.net MVC application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx). The very first sentence tells you that... There there's other Stackoverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4599977/75642) by a trusted person that says the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Controller actions are accessible for everybody by default. So I suppose, that you have set an `AuthorizeAttribute` somewhere higher and now you want to suppress it on the particular action `ResetPassword`. For this purpose, there is the attribut `[AllowAnonymous]`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string Email,string Key)
{
    //Do some thing
    return View();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
As Muhammad Adeel Zahid noted, this works only for the version 4 and above :-/ For MVC 3, you can use approach described here: [Securing your ASP.NET MVC 3 Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx)

Comment: The problem is I am not allowed to change forms authentication

Answer (score 0):

### Use `AuthorizeAttribute`

This will make it possible that only authenticated uses are authorized to execute this particular controller action. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx).

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string Email,string Key)
{
    //Do some thing
    return View();
}
```

> ***Note**: This works with any authentication method you may be using (even custom ones if written properly) as long as `Principal` and `User` objects instances are being populated. Default out-of-the-box authentication methods do populate them and if you're using some custom authentication method make sure they get populated.*

### Always secure - opt out

But apparently either your whole controller or the whole application is secured by the `AuthorizeAttribute`. In this case you should *opt-out* particular controller actions. As Juraj sais in MVC 4 you should simply use `AllowAnonymousAttribute` but in older versions you can write your own as [instructed on this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx).

This is the Microsoft preferred approach that you should be following.

Comment: The problem is I am not allowed to change forms authentication, so I must fined solution with forms authentication

Comment: @HalaAly: It doesn't really matter what kind of authentication you're using as long as your `Principal` and `User` objects are populated. Works with Windows authentication, forms authentication or any other custom authentication technique you may be using. The main idea is that **this works with forms authentication**.